# Youtube Data API: How to get recent activity types .like .favorite and .subscription

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are playing with the Youtube data API and want to get the

snippet.typestring:
`favorite`
`like`
`subscription`

however this only works for old  subscriptions (3 years), no recent activity for likes and favorites

in general the connection works as we can get recent video uploads but not these types
`favorite`
`like`
`subscription`

we tried connection through oauth and channelId + api key but had the same issues

we created the test account and made sure there is recent activity but nothing showed up

did anyone have experience with this or similar issues?

we used this
[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&mine=true&access_token=[TOKEN]](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&mine=true&access_token=%5BTOKEN%5D)
and
[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&channelId=UCxlF-pLQQUAHZSixTqHiwDQ&key=[API_KEY]](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&channelId=UCxlF-pLQQUAHZSixTqHiwDQ&key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Your url format is wrong.
it should be like this:

```
$jsonrl:
"https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=contentDetails,snippet&channelId=channelidhere&key=apikey"
```

favorite, like, subscription
You need to evaluate the videos separately for the subscription, and evaluate the channel id for the subscription.
example:

```
$videocount= $jsonurl->items[0]->statistics->videoCount;
$subscriberCount=$jhandle2->$jsonurl-->statistics->subscriberCount;
$viewCount= $jsonurl-->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;
```

Youtube Channel Id Find Demo: https://ytlarge.com/youtube/channel-id-finder/
Youtube data viewer Demo2: https://ytlarge.com/youtube/video-data-viewer/